# MySQL logic where function I think

Tags: mysql, if-statement, logic, where-clause

I have about 500 rows with simliar data to the 4 rows below, from this exmaple I only want two rows to be returned using the following logic:

**If `emp No` 817 `sal_id` = 2 `is_active` 0 then return 817 `sal_id` 1 OR IF `emp No` 820 `sal_id` = 2 `is_active` 1 then return 820 `sal_2`**

So `sal_id` 1 is always active by default and `sal_id` 2 should be returned instead of `sal_id` 1 if `is_active` is 1, hope that makes sense!

```
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+
| emp No | sal_id |   value   |    effective_date     | is_active |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+
|    817 |      1 | DED914E3B | 01/04/2013            |         1 |
|    817 |      2 | 0         | 0                     |         0 |
|    820 |      1 | 8238942BE | 02/04/2013            |         1 |
|    820 |      2 | EA42574E4 | 02/04/2013            |         1 |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

Giving me a result of:

```
+--------+--------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| emp No | sal_id |   value   | effective_date | is_active |
+--------+--------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
|    817 |      1 | DED914E3B | 01/04/2013     |         1 |
|    820 |      2 | EA42574E4 | 02/04/2013     |         1 |
+--------+--------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
```

Not sure this can even be done, please advise and thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking to return the active record from each `emp No` group?  But in the case of `emp No = 820` above, where both records are active, why return `sal_id = 2` instead of `sal_id = 1`?  And what about the case (not shown) where there is no active record?

Comment: Are there always two `sal_id`'s per employee, or might there be any number?

Comment: Yes, active record per employee but where sal_id record 2 is active is should be returned instead of sal_id 1 which will also be active.... and yes there are two types "Salary"=1 & "Hourly"=2 all employees will have a salary value as active but around half will be hourly paid and will have a active record id of 1 & 2 but only the id 2 should be returned in this case

Comment: Could be 1 or 2 per employee but ever more than 2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is stored in `employee_salary` this is a dirty hack;

```
select es.emp_no, es.sal_id, value, effective_date, is_active from employee_salary es
join ( 
     select emp_no, max(sal_id) as sal_id from employee_salary
         where is_active<>0
         group by emp_no
) selector
where es.emp_no=selector.emp_no and es.sal_id=selector.sal_id
```

Limitations:

- It is not easy to change the default from 2 to 1 without rewriting the SQL.
- Not clear to me how this approach would apply if the data were not in a table but a result from a SELECT, other than with a temporary table.
- Might not handle the case where `is_active=0` for **both** `sal_id=1` and `sal_id=2` as you need, currently no results are returned for that emp_no, is this what you want?
- As pointed out by Aya this generates a temp table which it then sorts without using an index, expect this to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is more verbose than Mark's, but should be more efficient, since it avoids using a temp table...

```
SELECT
    es1.emp_no,
    IF(es2.is_active=1, es2.sal_id, es1.sal_id) AS sal_id,
    IF(es2.is_active=1, es2.value, es1.value) AS value,
    IF(es2.is_active=1, es2.effective_date, es1.effective_date) AS effective_date,
    IF(es2.is_active=1, es2.is_active, es1.is_active) AS is_active
FROM employee_salary es1
    LEFT JOIN employee_salary es2 ON (es2.emp_no=es1.emp_no AND es2.sal_id=2)
WHERE es1.sal_id=1;
```

...which yields...

```
+--------+--------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| emp_no | sal_id | value     | effective_date | is_active |
+--------+--------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
|    817 |      1 | DED914E3B | 01/04/2013     |         1 |
|    820 |      2 | EA42574E4 | 02/04/2013     |         1 |
+--------+--------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
```

...and for which an EXPLAIN yields...

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | es1   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | es2   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

...compared to Mark's...

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | es              | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
|  2 | DERIVED     | employee_salary | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

You can strip out any of the `IF` clauses for which you don't actually need the values.

Comment: Thanks looking good and nearly there, but where there is only 1 record where sal_id = 1 it's not pulling that record to the result!!

Comment: @John Could you provide some example data?

Comment: @JohnOwen Works for me. The query works by joining the `sal_id=1` and `sal_id=2` records for each employee into a single row, for which the `LEFT JOIN` will produce `NULL` values for the `sal_id=2` part of the joined data if there's no matching record. Then it only returns the values for the `sal_id=2` case if its `is_active` is `1` (i.e. not `0` or `NULL`), otherwise it'll return the values for the `sal_id=1` case, regardless of their values. As Mark suggested, it'd help if you provide some example data for the failing case, and including the schema from `SHOW CREATE TABLE` would also help.

Comment: If there is only Sal_id 2 record (no Sal_id 1) it's not pulling through that record. It works fine if a Sal_id 1 exsits

Comment: @JohnOwen If you have cases like that, you'd be better off changing the schema to include both columns in each row. i.e. remove `sal_id` and have separate columns `yearly_salary`, and `hourly_rate`.